# R Calculate the difference between values from one to all the other columns

Tags: r

i am having some troubles to find the best and most efficient way to perform few calculations on my data in shiny app. I would like to at first calculate the difference between all the columns (except `ID`) to one column, create new columns for each (with specific name) and furthermore perform small calculation. I am going to explain it on the example data:

```
data <- structure(list(ID = 1:2, Zeit600 = c(601.782608695652, 602.625
), Zeit650 = c(504.705882352941, 546.666666666667), Zeit700 = c(321.26582278481, 
                                                                316.666666666667), Zeit750 = c(264.303797468354, 261.111111111111
                                                                ), Zeit800 = c(207.341772151899, 205.555555555556)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                   -2L), .Names = c("ID", "Zeit600", "Zeit650", "Zeit700", "Zeit750", 
                                                                                                                                                    "Zeit800"), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the same data in a form that its easier to have a look at:

```
  ID  Zeit600  Zeit650  Zeit700  Zeit750  Zeit800
1  1 601.7826 504.7059 321.2658 264.3038 207.3418
2  2 602.6250 546.6667 316.6667 261.1111 205.5556
```

What i would like to do is to:

**1.** Calculate the difference between all the columns  (except `ID`) to column named `Zeit800` and named it (if it is possible T800_the number next to Zeit).

*My original data is reactive in shiny, therefore the number of columns `Zeit...` will differ, only column `Zeit800` always stays.

The result will look like this:

```
  ID  Zeit600  Zeit650  Zeit700  Zeit750  Zeit800 T800_T600 T800_T650 T800_T700 T800_T750
1  1 601.7826 504.7059 321.2658 264.3038 207.3418  394.4408  297.3641  113.9241  56.96203
2  2 602.6250 546.6667 316.6667 261.1111 205.5556  397.0694  341.1111  111.1111  55.55556
```

**2.** Then i would like to perform small calculation, Calculate the difference between 800 and number which is next `Zeit...` in column names, and divide it by calculated values performed above at point **1** (`T800...`). So for example lets calculate this for column `Zeit600` for `ID=1`:

`800-600/T800_600 = 800-600/394.4408 = 0.507`

The whole data frame would look like:

```
  ID  Zeit600  Zeit650  Zeit700  Zeit750  Zeit800 T800_T600 T800_T650 T800_T700 T800_T750 Abkuehlrate_T800_600 Abkuehlrate_T800_650
1  1 601.7826 504.7059 321.2658 264.3038 207.3418  394.4408  297.3641  113.9241  56.96203            0.5070469            0.5044321
2  2 602.6250 546.6667 316.6667 261.1111 205.5556  397.0694  341.1111  111.1111  55.55556            0.5036902            0.4397394
  Abkuehlrate_T800_700 Abkuehlrate_T800_750
1            0.8777778            0.8777778
2            0.9000000            0.9000000
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now here's the whole operation in form of a function:

```
myfun <- function(var, compvar, data) {
  diffcol <- as.data.frame(lapply(data[var], function(x) x-data[compvar]))
  names(diffcol) <- paste(compvar, var, sep = "_")
  mydata <- cbind(data, diffcol)

  abkuehlrate <- as.data.frame(mapply(function(x, y) 
    (as.numeric(gsub("T", "", compvar))-as.numeric(gsub("T", "", x)))/y, var, diffcol, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
  names(abkuehlrate) <- paste("Abkuehlrate", compvar, gsub("T", "", var), sep = "_")
  mydata <- cbind(mydata, abkuehlrate)
  return(mydata)
}
```

You use it by feeding it the variables as strings of their name, and providing the data:

```
mydf <- myfun("T600", "T800", mydf)
```

This way, you can just use the function with a string of variable names, which you can extract from your data in any way you want. Example:

```
myvars <- names(mydf[,2:5])
newdf <- myfun(myvars, "T800", mydf)
```

Output:

```
> newdf
  ID     T600     T650     T700     T750     T800 T800_T600 T800_T650 T800_T700 T800_T750 Abkuehlrate_T800_T600
1  1 601.7826 504.7059 321.2658 264.3038 207.3418  394.4408  297.3641  113.9241  56.96203             0.5070469
2  2 602.6250 546.6667 316.6667 261.1111 205.5556  397.0694  341.1111  111.1111  55.55556             0.5036902

  Abkuehlrate_T800_T650 Abkuehlrate_T800_T700 Abkuehlrate_T800_T750
1             0.5044321             0.8777778             0.8777778
2             0.4397394             0.9000000             0.9000000
```

Edit: final small edit to get the exact variable names you wanted. If your variables have to be named `Zeit600` etc, just substitute `"Zeit"` for the `"T"` in the `gsub()` operations.

Comment: It looks very good! Just one thing, my data (in this case `mydf`) as it is in shiny, it has a reactive number of columns, this means there might be **2,3,5 or any other number of columns** `Zeit...`. That means, i cannot use `...mydf[,2:4]...`, the solution must be general

Comment: Well it does not really matter, but we need the difference columns to calculate the abkuehlraten columns

Comment: Interesting, but when i run Your code, i get Error: `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 3 In addition: Warning messages:
1: In (as.numeric(gsub("T", "", compvar)) - as.numeric(gsub("T", "",  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In (as.numeric(gsub("T", "", compvar)) - as.numeric(gsub("T", "",  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In (as.numeric(gsub("T", "", compvar)) - as.numeric(gsub("T", "",  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object..`

Comment: Thanks so much. However the difference column is correctly calculated, but unfortunatelly the abkuehlrate values are wrongly calculated i think (they do not match the correct values). .

Comment: I do have one more question to it, i have just noticed, if i have only one **ID** (ID = 1/only one data row, in shiny app dataset is reactive, depends on user input), then using Your function i get an error:`Error in names(abkuehlrate) <- paste("Abkuehlrate", compvar, gsub("T",  : 
  'names' attribute [4] must be the same length as the vector [1]`...Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Hey, I got you :) The problem was that `mapply` used a one-dimensional vector as a column of a `data.frame`, instead of a row. I fixed it by setting the `SIMPLIFY`-option to false, so that `mapply` does not try to coerce its output into a vector. Should work now with the new version :)

Answer (score 2):

```
subData <- subset(data,select = - c(ID, Zeit800))
numbers <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", names(subData)))
namesT <- paste0("T800_T",  numbers)
T800 <- subData-data$Zeit800
data[,namesT] <- T800
namesAbkuehlrate <- paste0("Abkuehlrate_T800_",  numbers)
data[,namesAbkuehlrate] <- mapply('/', (800-numbers), T800)
```