# group_by edit distance between rows over multiple columns

Tags: r, group-by, multiple-columns, edit-distance, rowwise

I have the following data frame.

#### Input:

```
class   id  q1  q2  q3  q4
Ali     12  1   2   3   3
Tom     16  1   2   4   2
Tom     18  1   2   3   4
Ali     24  2   2   4   3
Ali     35  2   2   4   3
Tom     36  1   2   4   2
```

1. ***class*** indicates the teacher's name,
2. ***id*** indicates the student user ID, and,
3. ***q1***, ***q2***, ***q3*** and ***q4*** indicate marks on different test questions

#### Requirement:

I am interested in finding potential cases of cheating. I hypothesise that if the students are in the same class and have similar scores on different questions, they are likely to have cheated.
For this, I want to calculate absolute distance or difference, grouped by ***class*** name, across multiple columns, i.e., all the test questions ***q1***, ***q2***, ***q3*** and ***q4***. And I want to store this information in a couple of new columns as below:

1. *difference*:
   For a given ***class*** name, it contains the pairwise distance or difference with all other students' ***id***. For a given class name, it stores the information as (id1, id2 = difference)
2. *cheating*:
   This column lists any ***id***'s based on the previously created new column where the difference was zero (or some threshold value). This will be a flag to alert the teacher that their student might have cheated.

```
class   id  q1  q2  q3  q4  difference                  cheating
Ali     12  1   2   3   3   (12,24 = 2), (12,35 = 2)    NA
Tom     16  1   2   4   2   (16,18 = 3), (16,36 = 0)    36
Tom     18  1   2   3   4   (16,18 = 3), (18,36 = 3)    NA
Ali     24  2   2   4   3   (12,24 = 2), (24,35 = 0)    35
Ali     35  2   2   4   3   (12,35 = 2), (24,35 = 0)    24
Tom     36  1   2   4   2   (16,36 = 0), (18,36 = 3)    16
```

Is it possible to achieve this using dplyr?

#### Related posts:

I have tried to look for related solutions but none of them address the exact problem that I am facing e.g.,

1. This post calculates the difference between all pairs of rows. It does not incorporate the group_by situation plus the solution is extremely slow: [R - Calculate the differences in the column values between rows/ observations (all combinations)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69691026/r-calculate-the-differences-in-the-column-values-between-rows-observations-a)
2. This one compares only two columns using stringdist(). I want my solution over multiple columns and with a group_by() condition: [Creating new field that shows stringdist between two columns in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64018484/creating-new-field-that-shows-stringdist-between-two-columns-in-r)
3. The following post compares the initial values in a column with their preceding values: [R Calculating difference between values in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48871114/r-calculating-difference-between-values-in-a-column)
4. This one compares values in one column to all other columns. I would want this but done row wise and through group_by(): [R Calculate the difference between values from one to all the other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41889438/r-calculate-the-difference-between-values-from-one-to-all-the-other-columns)

#### dput()

For your convenience, I am sharing data dput():

```
structure(list(class = 
c("Ali", "Tom", "Tom", "Ali", "Ali", "Tom"), 
id = c(12L, 16L, 18L, 24L, 35L, 36L), 
q1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), 
q2 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
q3 = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
q4 = c(3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to clustering the data, using `hclust()` for example. Once the relative distances are calculated and mapped, the cut the tree at the threshold of expected cheating.

This example I am using the standard `dist()` function to calculate differences, the stringdist function may be better or maybe another option is out there to try.

```
df<- structure(list(class = 
c("Ali", "Tom", "Tom", "Ali", "Ali", "Tom"), 
id = c(12L, 16L, 18L, 24L, 35L, 36L), 
q1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), 
q2 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
q3 = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
q4 = c(3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

#apply the standard distance function
scores <- hclust(dist(df[ , 3:6]))

plot(scores)

#divide into groups based on level of matching too closely
groups <- cutree(scores, h=0.1)

#summary table
summarytable <- data.frame(class= df$class, id =df$id, groupings =groups)

#select groups with more than 2 people in them
suspectgroups <- table(groups)[table(groups) >=2]

potential_cheaters <- summarytable %>% filter(groupings %in% names(suspectgroups)) %>% arrange(groupings) 
potential_cheaters
```

This works for this test case, but for larger datasets the height in the `cutree()` function may need to be adjusted. Also consider splitting the initial dataset by class to eliminate the chance of matching people between classes (depending on the situation of course).